# strip out a portion of url

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone know how to strip out a portion of url.

For example I have 3 img sources each residing in it's own div class called "showimage".

```
<div class="showimage"><img src="http://www.mydomain.com/image1-thumb.JPG" /></div>
<div class="showimage"><img src="http://www.mydomain.com/image2-thumb.JPG" /></div>
<div class="showimage"><img src="http://www.mydomain.com/image3-thumb.JPG" /></div>
```

I want all the urls to remove the "-thumb" so the img sources reads;

```
<div class="showimage"><img src="http://www.mydomain.com/image1.JPG" /></div>
<div class="showimage"><img src="http://www.mydomain.com/image2.JPG" /></div>
<div class="showimage"><img src="http://www.mydomain.com/image3.JPG" /></div>
```

I only have access to CSS, javascript or jQuery.

thanks for helping.

Comment: How about: `"<div class="showimage"><img src="http://www.mydomain.com/image1-thumb.JPG" /></div>".replace("-thumb", "")` or you need detailed answer using JS?

Comment: no i needed it using JS because I don't have access to the code. thanks for helping!

Comment: you are correct, but I have thousands of images that need to be  stripped so I can't specify all the urls.  I think i would need to do that if I used your code.

Answer (score 4):

```
$("div.showimage img").attr("src",function(){
    return this.src.replace("-thumb","");
});
```

Comment: @user721521: Did this really work? because the code is actually wrong. It should be `$("div.showimage img").attr("src",function(i, src){return src.replace("-thumb","");});` . `this` references the current element, not the `src` value.

Comment: @Felix Kling The code did not work before and The "works like a charm" was meant for jSang below.   I tested your code and jSang below and they both work.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$(".showimage img").each(function() {
    var imgSrc = $(this).attr("src");
    imgSrc = imgSrc.replace("-thumb","");
    $(this).attr("src",imgSrc);
});
```